# Laravel 5.2 test DOM changed

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have page that have button with id `new-item`, and when I click on it, javascript code loads a remote bootstrap modal with a form, and show the modal.

I want to test the functionality with the PHPUnit with Laravel. I have write this test:

```
$this->visit('/');
     ->click('new-item');
     ->seeElement('.modal');
```

The page is working fine, but the test fails. I gets error that the page have no `.modal` element, and it's also shows me the html of the page.
But the html looks like the original page before the remote modal was inserted to the page.

So how can I force the test to refresh the page content after the javascript changes the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Laravel uses PHPUnit and PHPBrowser for testing. PHPBrowser does not support Javascript. If you want to test javascript you will need to use something like selenium and codeception. Codeception has a built in Laravel adapter so it is still super easy to use. I have used it in many applications and it works really well.

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5

There are also other options for headless browsers that support javascript this is just one option.